# How to find logs when submitting resource type to Cloudformation Registry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am developing a [private resource type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/registry-private.html) for AWS [Cloudformation Registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/registry.html). I have designed my model schema and developed my handler code, [submitted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation-cli/latest/userguide/resource-type-walkthrough.html#resource-type-walkthrough-submit) it, and even successfully deployed a stack with my very own private resource type. Yay.

What i need to do now is inspect the logging thereof. As I had generated the scaffolding using the cfn init command, i merely added logging entries to the existing logger object.

e.g.

```
# Use this logger to forward log messages to CloudWatch Logs.
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
TYPE_NAME = "Myself::Test::Resourceful"

resource = Resource(TYPE_NAME, ResourceModel)
test_entrypoint = resource.test_entrypoint


@resource.handler(Action.CREATE)
def create_handler(
        session: Optional[SessionProxy],
        request: ResourceHandlerRequest,
        callback_context: MutableMapping[str, Any],
) -> ProgressEvent:
    model = request.desiredResourceState
    progress: ProgressEvent = ProgressEvent(
        status=OperationStatus.IN_PROGRESS,
        resourceModel=model,
    )
    # TODO: put code here

    LOG.info('Creating....')
```

According to the [literature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation-cli/latest/userguide/resource-type-develop.html#resource-type-develop-log),

> When you register a resource type using cfn submit, CloudFormation
> creates a CloudWatch log group for the resource type in your account.
> This enables you to access the logs for your resource to help you
> diagnose any faults. The log group is named according to the following
> pattern:
>
> /my-resource-type-stack-ResourceHandler-string
>
> Now, when you initiate stack operations for stacks that contain the
> resource type, CloudFormation delivers log events emitted by the
> resource type to this log group.

When submitting my resource type however (and even deploying it), a cannot see any LogGroup created in CloudWatch whatsoever. There is clearly something i am missing here.

**Please help me understand how to find the logging for my private Cloudformation registry resource types.**

Of course, i will be happy to provide any additional info needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Thanks to [@maslick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530077/20003774), all i had to do was **explicitly set an appropriate logging level**.

```
# Use this logger to forward log messages to CloudWatch Logs.

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOG.setLevel(logging.INFO)            # <- this line was missing
```

When deploying stack, log groups appears. Yay.